# getting paragraph representation for unseen paragraphs in doc2vec

Tags: classification, gensim, doc2vec

I would like to use genism doc2vec model for a classification task.
However, It seems like the gensim implementation of doc2vec requires to see all documents (train and test) to build the vocabulary before training the model. Otherwise, you get keyerror if you want to get document vector of a document that was not present when building the vocabulary. I wonder if my understanding is correct! In practice, one does not have access to the test data at the time of training.

Is there any way to update the vocabulary at the test time to be able to get document representation of test documents?

Answer (score 2):

You can only look-up learned document-vectors for material that was presented during training.

But, there is a method `infer_vector()` which can provide a new tokenized document to the the frozen, trained model, and return a 'best-fit' vector. It approximates what would have been returned if the new document was available during training. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.infer_vector